# Data don't appear in html page in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have problem with my data , it's don't appear in my html page i tried do this but nothing happen

model.py :

```
class BestArticals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    url = models.URLField(default="",max_length=240)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

veiws.py :

```
def Best_Articals(request):
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()
    context = {'best_posts' : best_posts}
    return render(request,'android/side_bar_good_posts.html',context=context)
```

html page :

```
{% for post in best_posts %}
<ul style="text-align:right">
  <li> <img src="{{post.get_image}}" height="80px" width="80px"> <a href="{{post.url}}" style="color:black"> {{post.name}}  </a> </li><br>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

what is the problem here

Comment: Did you add the `media` views to the `urls.py`?

Comment: no , how to add it please

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: yes now i add it , but nothing happen 

Comment: any help ? 
note * if i add url for it it work when i open the url in browser and when i remove url from url.py it's don't work why ? i want just show it in other html page like include 'ttest.html'